# Problem dynamically populating a select field based on the selection of another select field

Tags: 7, ajax

I have seen quite a few questions on here about the "Illegal choice has been detected" error when trying to load a select field with AJAX in Drupal 7. I have not yet been able to find an answer to solve my issue though. I have 3 select boxes Year, Make, and Model. When I select a year the makes populate fine. When I select a Make, I get the Illegal choice detected error and the models do not populate. But if I choose another make everything works fine. Can anyone help me figure out why the first attempt doesn't work? Here is the code that I have

```
function formblock($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['year'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => _load_years(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'formblock_make_loader',
      'wrapper' => 'make_div',
    ),
  );

  $makes = array('empty' => 'Select Make',);
  if (isset($form_state['values']['year'])) {
    $makes = drupal_map_assoc(_load_make($form_state['values']['year']));
  }

  $form['make'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $makes,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="make_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'formblock_model_loader',
      'wrapper' => 'model_div',
    ),
  );

  $models = array("empty" => "No Model");
  if (isset($form_state['values']['make'])) {
    $models = drupal_map_assoc(_load_model($form_state['values']['year'], form_state['values']['make']));
  }

  $form['model'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => t($models),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="model_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if (isset($form_state['values']['make'])) {
    $form['model']['#options'] = _load_model($form_state['values']['year'], $form_state['values']['make']);
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function formblock_make_loader($form, $form_state) {
  // The form has already been submitted and updated. We can return the replaced
  // item as it is.
  return $form['make'];
}

function formblock_model_loader($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['model'];
}

function formblock_submit($form, &$formstate){

}

function _load_years(){
  $thisyear = date('Y');
  $years = array();

  foreach(range(1990, $thisyear) as $year) {
    $years[$year] = $year;
  }
  return $years;  // array
}

function _load_make($year) {
  $makes = array();

  // Make API call and get an array of makes

  return $makes;  // array
}

function _load_model($year, $make) {
  $models = array();

  // Make API call and get an array of models

  return $models;  //array
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally. I don't fully understand it, if anyone sees what happened and can explain it I would appreciate it. To fix it I changed

```
$makes = array('empty' => 'Select Make',);
if (isset($form_state['values']['year'])) {
  $makes = drupal_map_assoc(_load_make($form_state['values']['year']));
}
```

to

```
if(isset($form_state['values']['year'])) {
  $makes = drupal_map_assoc(_load_make($form_state['values']['year']));
}
else {
  $makes = array('' => 'Select Make');
}
```

and

```
$models = array("empty" => "No Model");
if (isset($form_state['values']['make'])) {
  $models = drupal_map_assoc(_load_model($form_state['values']['year'], form_state['values']['make']));
}
```

to

```
$models = array('' => 'Select makes');
if (!empty($form_state['values']['make'])) {
  $models = drupal_map_assoc(_load_model($form_state['values']['year'], $form_state['values']['make']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping your model select options array in `t()`

i.e: `'#options' => t($models)` vs `'#options' => $models`

Try this instead, it might work:

```
  $form['model'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $models,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="model_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately that did not fix the problem.